# 80s/90s animated sci-fi show with an elegant-looking spaceship

Tags: story-identification, animation

I am looking for a show I watched in Germany as a kid in the early-to-mid 90s on a VHS tape. It was an animated Science-Fiction show (or even movie), not sure if Cartoon or Anime. Here are vague points I remember:

- The cover on the VHS showed a black spaceship landed on an alien planet.
- In contrast to the cover I remember one scene with a tall, elegant-looking spaceship of silver or similar bright colour. It is characterized by rounded corners and smooth lines rather than a "boxy" design. There is a tall "neck" with the command bridge on top or on the side of it.
- In a scene the ship and its crew defend themselves from incoming asteroids or maybe enemies. The pacing of the scene was rather slow and the scene itself was quite dark. It had a realistic feel to it.

Unfortunately this is all I can remember certainly.

Comment: Was the show in German?

Comment: The show was in German, but I am certain it was dubbed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally found it! It is actually **[Cyborg 009 – Legend of the Super Galaxy](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0188535/)** from 1980, a continuation movie to the Cyborg 009 anime series.

The described starship can be seen in the upper left of the cover:

[image: Cyborg 009]

In the movie the team tests the weapons of the starship on a couple of asteroids creating a big chain reaction of explosions. Later on there is a space battle with an enemy. This is what I kind of remembered.

The German VHS is this one:

[image: German VHS]

There we can see the black ship landed on a planet. The German title here is: "Der galaktische Frieden" which translates to "Galactic Peace". The video is just 30 minutes long and is one part of a VHS series called "Abenteuer im Weltraum" (English: "adventures in space"), which represents a German cut of the movie. It is dubbed in German. To make the connection of these titles to Cyborg 009 was pretty difficult.

Answer (score 5):

This could be [*Once Upon a Time... Space*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Once_Upon_a_Time..._Space), a French - Japanese series first aired in 1982.

According to the linked Wikipedia page, it was broadcast in Germany too, so it's quite likely that it was available on VHS some time later.

The ships have a remarkable design, with bright colors (silver/white + yellow + blue) and rounded shapes; they also seem to feature an elevated command bridge. Unfortunately, I could not find any image matching your description of a *"black ship"*.

[image: spaceship from Once Upon a Time ... Space]

[image: spaceship from Once Upon a Time ... Space]

I have very little firsthand memories of this series, but episode #15 is set in the rings of Saturn, which could match the *"asteroids"* detail you remember.

Comment: That is not it, but it helps to specify. The characters were more detailed and realistic. There also was a black crew member. The battle scene was rather dark and gritty. It was not "happy" sci-fi I suppose.